# need help decoding using cryptography fernet

Tags: python, encryption, password-encryption

I can't seem to be able to `decrypt` lines with the key used in encryption. and always get an "invalid token" decryption error'

I expect to add a password using the programme, encrypting it, and then write to file. If you open a file, all you'll see is encrypted text, and you can only see your passwords using the programme itself.

Here is my code:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = b'Sw42CeEyZCyRyct0Ly2loEga9D4iv6tF0WRiTLKVdDA='
fkey = Fernet(key)



def add():
    app = input("enter app name ").upper()
    name = input("enter account name ")
    password = input("enter account password ")
    with open("passwords2.txt", 'a') as f:

        original = "{}: {} | {} ".format(app, name, password)
        inbytes = original.encode()
        originalencrypted = fkey.encrypt(inbytes)
        f.write(str(originalencrypted) + "\n")


def read():
    with open("passwords2.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(fkey.decrypt(line.strip().encode()).decode())


while True:
    operation = input("would you like to read, add, or quit (q) ")
    if operation == "read":
        read()
    elif operation == "add":
        add()
    elif operation == "q" or operation == "quit":
        quit()
    else:
        print("invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `str(originalencrypted)` (It creates string like this `"b'...'"`, rather than convert the `bytes` to `str` using some defined encoding).

You either want to convert `bytes` to `str` properly: `originalencrypted.decode('utf-8')`.

Or you want to write bytes to the file directly:

```
with open("passwords2.txt", 'ab') as f:
  ...
  f.write(originalencrypted)
  f.write("\n".encode('utf-8'))
```